# ¿Cómo concatenar filas en una sola fila separadas por comas de una sola columna?

Tags: sql

```
Select  E.EXC_Nombre from Bloqueos as B,
 Excursiones as E
Where B.BloqueosId = 69 and E.ExcursionesId IN (
SELECT 
      [BLE_ExcursionId]

  FROM [BloqueoExcursions]
  Where BLE_BloqueoID = 69)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Michael. Puedes explicar mejor lo que pides? Pon ejemplos de la estructura actual de la consulta y el resultado que te gustaria obtener. Mejora la explicacion siguiendo [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: la base de datos tambien aclara por favor.

Comment: ////////Tabla :Excursiones:
ExcursionesId EXC_Nombre  
2       Tangol
3       estadioo
4       Visita
5             Pampa
7       aa
8        bbb
21            cc
22       mmm

///////////Tabla: Bloqueos
BloqueosId  
69
70
71
//////////Tabla:BloqueoExcursion

BloqueoExcursionId   BLE_ExcurionId  BLE_BloqueoId   
11          8  1
12   3  1
17   4  66
20   2  3
21   7  3
22   3  67
23   8  67
36   8  68
37   3  68
38   8  69
39   3  69 
40   4  70
41   21  70 
42   5  71
43   2  71

Comment: ahi tengo 3 tabla gbianchi

Comment: Michael revisa por favor [ask], el sitio reporto una pregunta similar a esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102679/c%C3%B3mo-concatenar-filas-en-una-sola-fila-separadas-por-comas-de-una-sola-columna

Answer (score 2):

Si es la última versión de SQL Server (2017) puedes usar la función STRING_AGG() para concatenar los valores de fila en una cadena de caracteres con separadores.

Si es una versión anterior a la 2017 puedes usar FOR XML PATH, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
STUFF((SELECT ',' + t.EXC_Nombre FROM 
(
   SELECT E.EXC_Nombre
   FROM 
      Bloqueos B
      INNER JOIN Excursiones E ON B.BloqueosId = E.BloqueosId
         AND B.BloqueosId = 69
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BloqueoExcursions WHERE BLE_BloqueoID = B.BloqueosId)
) t
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)'), 1, 1, '');
```